# Facebook like button showing likes from root domain name

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've implemented a like button on this page

http://www.radfan.com/pages/radiator-calculator (should have 0 likes)

However, it is showing likes from this page

http://www.radfan.com/ (197 likes)

If I cancel the like then it drops to 196.

Using open graph I can see that both pages like count drops to 196 so they are in sync.

What have I implemented wrong? I am assuming it's a stupid mistake because on the site's blog all the pages/articles have their own (much lower) like counts.

Help would be great

UPDATE 1: Website is built on Shopify

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

I have tried multiple things including setting up a test page on a separate website that likes a specific url on the problematic website but the like only applies itself to the website and not the page.

I tried a different website eg. (http://drupal.org/project/addthis) and found that it worked correctly which indicates that there is something in the set up of my website url's that is causing the issue. At this stage I am not sure what this could be - perhaps facebook checks a few things before adding the like (including the web page response). Maybe rewrites are a problem?

My site is a Drupal 7 website that uses the domain access module. Is your constructed using a CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't specifying a URL when you create the like button.

If that still doesn't work then include a url with your like buttons like so (Assuming you're using the HTML5 button code):

```
<div data-href="http://www.radfan.com/pages/radiator-calculator" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```